# Boundaries not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I made a simple game in HTML that basically draws a sprite inside a canvas box and allows me to move it around via the arrow keys. But for some reason when I put boundaries on the sprite so that it won't leave the canvas, it didn't work out so well.

Here is an image of the sprite in the canvas (the canvas is the box in which the yellow sprite is inside of)

[image]

The sprite *does* have boundaries, at which it can't go further, but I wanted them to be AT the canvas lines. Right now it's constrained to some invisible box WITHIN the canvas. But nothing I see in the code is justifying my error. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
// JavaScript Document

var canvasWidth = 800;
var canvasHeight = 600;

$('#gameCanvas').attr('width', canvasWidth);
$('#gameCanvas').attr('height', canvasHeight);

var keysDown = {};

$('body').bind('keydown', function(e){
 keysDown[e.which] = true;
});

$('body').bind('keyup', function(e){
 keysDown[e.which] = false;
});

var canvas = $('#gameCanvas')[0].getContext('2d');
var FPS = 30;
var image = new Image();
image.src = "ship.png";

var playerX = (canvasWidth/2) - (image.width/2);
var playerY = (canvasHeight/2) - (image.height/2);

setInterval(function() {
update();
draw();
}, 1000/FPS);

function update(){
if(keysDown[37]){
    playerX -= 10;
}
if(keysDown[38]){
    playerY -= 10;
}
if(keysDown[39]){
    playerX += 10;
}
if(keysDown[40]){
    playerY += 10;
}

playerX = clamp(playerX, 0, canvasWidth - image.width);
playerY = clamp(playerY, 0, canvasHeight - image.height);

}

function draw() {
canvas.clearRect(0,0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
canvas.strokeRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
canvas.drawImage(image, playerX, playerY);
}

function clamp(x, min, max){
return x < min ? min : (x > max ? max : x);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit confused by the perceived error so here is a crack at it.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/h4t8fadk)**

What I did was added a `load` event listener for the image to make sure its fully loaded before starting the update,

```
image.addEventListener('load', function () {
    update();
});
```

Notice I just call update, and  your update function calls draw, then the end of `draw()` calls `requestAnimationFrame(update)`

Always use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) to do animations rather than intervals. You should notice it acting much smoother now.

I also added a bounding box around the image so you can see the boundaries. However if your issue is you want the image itself to go up against the borders of the canvas you just need to crop your image resource.

You can also do that with `drawImage`

**[Live Demo Cropped](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/fn4s6rx9/)**

Just use all 9 parameters of `drawImage` like so

```
drawImage(image, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, 
                 destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight)
```

so to crop it you could do

```
var cropX = 80,
    cropY = 20;

canvas.drawImage(image, 
                 cropX, cropY, image.width-cropX, image.height-cropY, 
                 playerX, playerY,image.width-cropX,image.height-cropY);
```

And it will draw the cropped image instead now.

One more suggestion is not to use jQuery for this, you don't need it you can select your `canvas` element without it using `getElementById` or [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) you can also bind your events using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

**Code in its entirety.**

```
// JavaScript Document

var canvasWidth = 800;
var canvasHeight = 600;

$('#gameCanvas').attr('width', canvasWidth);
$('#gameCanvas').attr('height', canvasHeight);

var keysDown = {};

$('body').bind('keydown', function (e) {
    keysDown[e.which] = true;
});

$('body').bind('keyup', function (e) {
    keysDown[e.which] = false;
});

var canvas = $('#gameCanvas')[0].getContext('2d');
var FPS = 30;
var image = new Image();
image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";

image.src = "http://i.imgur.com/LfcwdP7.gif";
image.addEventListener('load', function () {
    update();
});

var playerX = (canvasWidth / 2) - (image.width / 2);
var playerY = (canvasHeight / 2) - (image.height / 2);



function update() {
    if (keysDown[37]) {
        playerX -= 10;
    }
    if (keysDown[38]) {
        playerY -= 10;
    }
    if (keysDown[39]) {
        playerX += 10;
    }
    if (keysDown[40]) {
        playerY += 10;
    }

    playerX = clamp(playerX, 0, canvasWidth - image.width);
    playerY = clamp(playerY, 0, canvasHeight - image.height);

    draw();
}

function draw() {
    canvas.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    canvas.strokeRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    canvas.strokeRect(playerX, playerY, image.width, image.height);
    canvas.drawImage(image, playerX, playerY);

    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

function clamp(x, min, max) {
    return x < min ? min : (x > max ? max : x);

}
```

Comment: Nice, however, it's crops image, but it doesn't solves the boundary collision. 
http://gyazo.com/2cc7d9de33c8dbd502524b89ffc2a3bc

As you can see on image, it doesn't go further. You need to modify also the 'clamp'ing code `playerX = clamp(playerX, 0, canvasWidth - image.width + cropX);
playerY = clamp(playerY, 0, canvasHeight - image.height + cropY);` Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Volter9/fn4s6rx9/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working perfectly. The image **IS** touching the boundaries and doesn't go beyond. Maybe I didn't understand your problem, so please comment to clarify what you need.

The demo on jsfiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/8x5yv233/

Note: I think you need to wait for picture to load, before doing anything. Something like that:

```
var image = new Image();

image.onload = function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        update();
        draw();
    }, 1000/FPS);
}

image.src = 'yourpic.png';
```

Comment: When I said I wanted it to touch the boundaries I meant the utmost point of the sprite is allowed to touch the black lined box, but not go beyond. Right now the sprite can't even get to the black line because for some reason the boundary is smaller than the black lined box.

Comment: That's because your image have too many transparent space, that's why your image is not touching it. You need to clip it with PhotoShop or GIMP so it would have correct boundary.

Comment: But I did. I used Photoshop at I used the magic eraser tool to make the background transparent :/ But the image still has a border around it that touches the canvas line first, thus stopping it from moving further.

Comment: No, you need to change image's size for that. You can try to use crop tool.